# Set ActionMailer to use "foo.fr.erb" when I18n.locale is set to :en

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have this code:

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def foo
    recipients "bar@example.com"
    from       "foo@example.com"
    subject    "Foo"
    body       :var => "value"
  end

end
```

With two views in `app/views/mailer`:

- `foo.en.erb`
- `foo.fr.erb`

When I use `Mailer.deliver_foo`, the view used to build the email is `foo.en.erb` since `I18n.locale` is set to `:en`. Is there a way to bypass that and use `foo.fr.erb`, other than temporarly setting the locale to `:fr`, sending the email and then reverting back to `:en`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer [here](http://blog.raykosite.com/2010/06/12/rails-actionmailer-i18n-template-trick).

```
def foo user
  @template = "#{ActionMailer::Base::template_root}/mailer/foo.fr.erb"

  recipients "bar@example.com"
  from       "foo@example.com"
  subject    "Foo"
  body       :var => "value"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Had trouble with this so this seems like a reasonable place to post my findings

Rails will automatically find the template based on I18n.locale

But, This is WRONG: `foo.html.fr.erb`

This, is the correct way to name things: `foo.fr.html.erb`